# Dynamic temp table

Tags: sql

I have to create a dynamic temp table in sql server, based in a list of columns, for example, I have a table ListOfColumns that has many names of columns inside that refers to a real table

```
ListOfColumns
ColumnNameA
ColumnNameB
ColumnNameC
```

I create a function to get a string with all these columns in this format:

```
"ColumnNameA, ColumnNameB, ColumnNameC"
```

Now I need to create my temp table based on those columns that are in a real table called Report. I can have more or less columns (Its a dynamic report column generator)

I need to do a dynamic SQL, I don't have the datatypes for each column, I would like to create a temp table with dynamic sql and inherit the datatypes of my Report table. Is there any way of doing this?

By the way... I don't want to use global variables.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your Report table looks something like this:

```
create table Report (
  ColumnNameA varchar(4),
  ColumnNameB integer,
  ColumnNameC integer,
  ColumnNameD varchar(8),
  ColumnNameE bit,
  ColumnNameF integer
 );
```

You can create the following procedure:

```
create proc copy_table @col_names varchar(128)
as
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @col_names + ' into ReportTemp from Report where 1 = 0'
EXEC(@SQLQuery);
```

and call it using the comma separated columns string you have, as below:

```
exec copy_table @col_names = 'ColumnNameA, ColumnNameB, ColumnNameC'
```

and you should have your table created with the correct column types. To test it, insert one row and then query it.

```
insert into ReportTemp values ('abc', 1, 2 );
select * from ReportTemp;
```

To see this in action, check out this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c886/2).

Note that, this will **not** carry over constraints, indices, etc -- just the column names and types.

Comment: Thanks @ibrahim but ReportTemp is not a temp table on the fly, I don't want to create a physical table, based on your example, I want to create a temp table.

Comment: You can add the hash before the table name and it should create it as a temp table.

Comment: but I am not able to insert into it, or query it, even within the procedure!?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a dynamic temporary table.

The reason is that the temporary table is associated with the SQL session.  When you execute dynamic SQL, it creates a new session that terminates at the end of the session.  So, the table gets created during the `exec`.  Then it gets dropped (or out of context) when control moves back to the calling procedure.

Here are some work-arounds, none of which you might like:

1. Create a table with a canonical prefix, such as "_" to represent a working table.  Then drop this table in the stored procedure and catch exceptions to drop it in almost all cases.
2. Create a temporary table with all possible column values.
3. Create your own "temporary" database for such working tables.
4. Use generic column names and keep the correspondence from these generic columns to your columns somewhere else.